# Is Padma Purana a bad Purana?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, krishna, puranas, padma-purana

I have heard that Padma Purana gives wrong descriptions of God such as Vishnu creating Shiva.

Does Padma Purana tell us real or duplicate stories?

Comment: Brahman is one and people call him with different names. Shaivaites call him as Shiva whereas Vaishnvaites call him as Vishnu. Indirectly all puranas say the same story that trimurti( Brahma,Narayana and Rudra aka Shankra) was created by Brahman( Shiva=Vishnu). So you can't say Padma purana is wrong because it says Vishnu created Shiva. Understand the allegory in our Puranas.

Comment: all the puranas are written by humans, human can make mistakes.

Comment: Which Purana is such that does not do it? **Devi Puraana** says Devi created Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva. **Shiva Puraana** says Trimurti and all are made by Shiva. **Vishnu Puraanam** says Vishnu does it. **Brahma Vaivarta Puraana** says Krishna created all Vishnu, Shiva , Brahma , Devi all. **Ganesha Puraana** says Ganesha created Trimurti. **Devi Puraana** also says Shiva, Brahma, Vishnu, Prakriti all are part of Only One ParaBrahma. So what is truth you can decide.

Comment: There are no contradictions (or very rare) among shrutis. They are presented as it is. There is however a lot of contradiction in smiritis, they contradict other smritis, shrutis or even themselves at times. They were compiled at a very later stage, with multiple independent people involved (most probably) with whatever knowledge was left at that time. They might also have a lot of glorified personal opinions of the authors. In case of any contradiction, shurits should be referred. see: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57195/how-does-one-deal-with-contradiction-in-scriptures

Answer (score 6):

I don't think any Puran is BAD..

There are multiple stories about the origins of the Lord vishnu and Lord Shiva.

- Shrimad Bhagvatam states that Lord Shiva appeared from between the
  eyebrows of Lord Brahma.
- Shiva Purana states that Lord Vishnu
  orignated when Lord Shiva rubbed some nectar on his ankle.
- Vishnu Purana says that Lord Shiva originated from the eyebrows of the lord
  vishnu

But when you read any of two puran completely then you will come to a real point that.**It is from Sadashiv and Prakriti that Lord Bramha, Vishnu and Rudra are originated or born .**

All three Lords are ever present in their esoteric form ,but, they get manifested in different physical worlds in different ways at different times.

**As per Shiv Puran** after each cycle of creation and destruction the three Lords manifest in different ways. Sometimes it may start with Lord Vishnu, sometimes with Lord Brahma and sometimes with Lord Shiva, sometimes, even differently.

After the latest destruction, Bramha ji came out of a Lotus which grew out of Lord Vishnu's Navel ( now the real esoteric meaning of this story is totally different) and Lord Rudra came out of Lord Bramha's fore head or eyebrow. 
But, it is also written that before this 'birth' of Lord Shiva and Lord Brahma all three had met each other where the events to follow were known. (The story where Lord Shiva appears in form of infinite tower of energy and then there are more times when they meet before Lord Bramha starts creating Universe). It was one such time that Lord Brahma requested Lord Rudra to be born in the physical universe through him, and therefore, the stories of Lord Rudra coming out of Lord Bramha's eyebrow/tear.

Comment: Where in Shiva Purana is such thing state as you have written, please give Chapter name, khanda name et cetera

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Srimad Bhagwatam is that which states the absolute truth. It is considered as Nirgun meaning it is for the people who are free from 3 modes(gunas) of the nature. Any other purana which is not based on Krishna or any Vishnu Tattva , is only to bewilder the people so that , it increase there faith in the particular God like Lord Shiva , Devi mata etc. But Srimad Bhagwatam is the Supreme Absolute Truth. Even Shiv Ji explains in Padma Purana that the scriptures which do announce Bhagwan Hari(Krishna) as the Supreme of all , are only to bewilder people.
You can watch the videos--
Lord Shiva Stating--

https://youtu.be/ADg1h9PthnM?si=KgO_xGDCjESenZte

Bhagwatam is the supreme---

https://youtu.be/YGupSE2hU1w?si=k3k5W0VwNTBCU6WS

All Glories to Guru Maharaj !
All Glories to Shrila Prabhupada !
Hare Krishna !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Srimad Bhagavatam is not nirguna. The vaishnavite classifications (Padma,Garuda) put it under the banner of 'sattvika' and the Shaivite classifications(Skanda) put it under 'Tamasika'. So it's still under the three gunas only. No scripture in the whole world can be free of 3 gunas. Vedas themselves are under the 3 gunas as per puranas.

Comment: // Shiv Ji explains in Padma Purana that the scriptures which do announce Bhagwan Hari(Krishna) as the Supreme of all , are only to bewilder people.// Scriptures like Shiva purana and linga purana themselves directly annotate the Veda mantras in countless occasions wherever they declare Shiva supreme. So if these puranas are tamasika and for bewilderment, then so are the vedas themselves.

Comment: If Any scripture having Shiva-para stuti causes it to become tamsika, Then Bhagavatam itself has 4 Shiva-para stutis. So even Bhagavatam cannot even be purely sattvika, let alone nirguna.

Answer (score 2):

If you label a text as 'bad', just because it does not conform to your views, it only shows your prejudice. Any classification of any text as good or bad should be based on some other valid text, and not on personal belief.

The author of all Puranas is Sri Vyasa himself. The right question one must be asking is why there are conflicting passages in different Puranas, the answer to which one would get from a proper Guru, not from the internet.

Comment: He is not labeling.. he is simply asking.. this is a question and answer site..so he can ask his questions here..

Comment: This looks like a comment and not a proper answer.