# Does the Matsya Purana forbid one to read Rajasika and Tamasika Puranas?

Tags: puranas, padma-purana, gunas, matsya-purana

Padma Purana, Uttara Khanda, Chapter 236 states:

> सात्विका मोक्षदाः प्रोक्ताः राजसा सर्वदा अशुभाः ।
>
> तथैव तामसा देवि निरयप्राप्तिहेतवः ।।
>
> Among these puranas Satvika Puranas lead one to liberation, **Rajasa do not cause good and Tamasa puranas lead one to hell.** (236.2)

Now, this guna based classification of Puranas, I have been told, is also present in the Matsya (which is a Tamasika Purana incidentally in the Padma Purana). I want to know whether the Matsya Purana does indeed mention a classification of the Puranas on the basis of gunas. If yes, does it discourage one to read Rajasika and Tamasika Puranas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of tamasic purana if it leads to hell?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/what-is-the-purpose-of-tamasic-purana-if-it-leads-to-hell)

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22366/is-the-notion-of-sattvik-tamasic-and-rajasic-puranas-genuine  and  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/is-padma-purana-a-bad-purana?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Matsya Purana indeed classifies the eighteen Puranas according to gunas **but it doesn't explicitly discourage one to read Rajasika and Tamasika Puranas or even state them to be inferior to Sattvika Puranas**:

> The glory of Hari is greater in Sattvika Puranas; the glory of Brahma is greater in Rajasika Puranas; and that of Agni and Shiva greater in Tamasika Puranas. In mixed Puranas, the glory of Sarasvati and the pitrs is said to be greater. (**Matsya Purana, Chapter 53, Verses 67-68**)